# Ansible, write certain elements from variable to a file

Tags: ansible

My Ansible playbook is currently printing certificates that are about to expire to the screen. These are my plays:

```
- name: Setting cert facts.
      set_fact:
        certData: "{{ certs.json | json_query('items[*].{expires: validityEnd, cn: cn, serial: serialHex, id: id}') }}"
      no_log: true

- name: Certs expiring within {{ expireDays }} days.
      debug:
        msg:
          - "Following certs have expired or are expiring within {{ expireDays }} days"
          - "ID: {{ item.id }}"
          - "CN: {{ item.cn }}"
          - "Serial: {{ item.serial }}"
          - "Expiration Date: {{ item.expires }}"
          - "Expiring in:  {{ expire_days }} days."
      vars:
        expire_days: "{{ (( item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')) - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }}"
      loop: "{{ certData }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cn }}  expires: {{ (item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }} days."
      when: expire_days | int <= expireDays
      register: expired_certs
```

Then I want to print only the **"cn"** values to a file, preferably in comma-delimited or new-line delimited format.

I tried doing this, but it prints nothing to the file:

```
- name: Create file with expiring certs.
      copy:
        dest: "./cert_expiring.txt"
        content: "{{ expired_certs.results | json_query('item[*].{id: id, cn: cn}') }}"
```

This is what an element in `{{ expired_certs }}` looks like:

```
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [{
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "item": {
            "cn": "node1.corp.com",
            "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:18+00:00",
            "id": 705,
            "serial": "1111"
        },
        "msg": [
            "Following certs have expired or are expiring within 90 days",
            "ID: 705",
            "CN: node1.corp.com",
            "Serial: 1111",
            "Expiration Date: 2020-11-05T15:20:18+00:00",
            "Expiring in:  -195 days."
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have figured out a way to accomplish this.
I changed the "Certs expiring within {{ expireDays }} days." play to this:

```
- name: Certs expiring within {{ expireDays }} days.
      lineinfile:
        dest: "./cert_expiring.txt"
        line: "{{ item.cn }}"
        state: present
        create: yes
      vars:
        expire_days: "{{ (( item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')) - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }}"
      loop: "{{ certData }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cn }}  expires: {{ (item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }} days."
      when: expire_days | int <= expireDays
```

This seems to be printing one CN per line.

Comment: looking forward to other suggestions on how to accomplish this.